# Hibernate should update only certain fields in the database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, caching, jpa

I have a database trigger which executes on insertion of data. From the application end, I use hibernate to update the same table which is update by the database TRIGGER. The data which was updated by Trigger gets overwritten by the older data when I update the data from the application end.I figured out that the cached value in hibernate is not in sych with the value from the database. Is there a proper way to get around this? The cache I am talking about is First level cache.

EDIT - Hibernate should update certain fields in the database and other fields in the database should be updated by the TRIGGER. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use refresh:

```
session.merge(entity);
session.flush();
//the trigger has been called
session.refresh(entity); 
//the entity will reflect the trigger changes
```

Comment: In my case, the call to "refresh" cleans up my new data as well. Suppose I want to update only specific fields from the database. These are the only field that are changed by the TRIGGER. The other fields of the table would be modified from the application. Lets say there are two   colmuns in the database NAME and DOB. Say the DOB is updated by the TRIGGER and NAME is updated by the application. So when I retrieve the object from the database, I want to save the new NAME and the latest DOB from the database (not the one which is cached).

Comment: Then the DOB proeprty should be marked with: @Column(name = "dob", insertable = false, updatable = false)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was really what is mentioned in the **EDIT** of the question. The simple solution to the  problem is as mentioned by Vlad in the comments. Mark the columns as @Column(name = "dob", insertable = false, updatable = false). This is help avoid any major surprises if hibernate updates the table.